# MYSQL - Select dISTINCT values in two columns

Tags: mysql

I want to select last time where sender_id or receiver_id = 20. Let me run you through a quick example.

```
Table:
sender_id   receiver_id     created_time
20            30              1
30            20              2
20            30              3
20            40              4
40            20              5
20            20              6
20            30              7
50            60              9

Result:
sender_id   receiver_id     created_time
40            20              5
20            30              7
```

Comment: SELECT * from table where sender_id = 20 or receiver_id = 20, is there more to it?

Comment: How about record `(20, 20, 6)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), 
       GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id),
       MAX(created_time)
FROM mytable
WHERE 20 IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), 
         GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
```

The above query produces one additional record for entry `(20, 20, 6)`. You can add an additional predicate in the `WHERE` clause if you want to rule out records having the same `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM new_table AS t1
WHERE
(sender_id = 20 OR receiver_id = 20)
AND
(t1.created_time >= 
 (SELECT MAX(created_time) FROM new_table WHERE sender_id = t1.sender_id)
)
```